# How many Guardians are in Zelda: Breath of the Wild?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I'm curious from a lore perspective - how many Guardians are there in Zelda: a Breath of the Wild, including both the destroyed Guardians, and the active ones that have been corrupted by Ganon (including the immobile ones)? It doesn't look like there's an answer on any of the wikis I've checked, nor on any of the walkthrough sites that turn up on a Google search. Does the number of Guardians in the game match the number of Guardians in the tapestry depicting the events 10000 years prior to the game?

I'm primarily interested in the main, full-sized hexapedal variety of Guardian, but if you also want to include tallies of the Guardian Scouts, fliers, and turrets, that would also be fine.

Comment: I'd say that the tapestry would be inaccurate, purely used for depiction of "a large force", for the reasons you've pointed out, such as the variety of guardians available in the game.

Comment: In addition to the many you can see, lore-wise there will be many that are buried, and possibly hundreds of thousands still in the vaults below the castle.

Comment: @OrangeDog My understanding is that the guardians that were being stored under the castle were released by Calamity Ganon when he took them over and raised the pillars containing them from the ground.

Comment: @nick012000 it was my understanding that there were still loads down there, which is how they respawn.

Comment: @OrangeDog Do you have a source for that? I had assumed that they respawned due to the Malice that powers them when they’re under Calamity Ganon’s control.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MrCheeze's [BOTW Object Map](https://objmap-legacy.zeldamods.org/) lists the following items:

- 46 Guardian Stalkers
- 29 Guardian Skywatchers
- 20 Guardian Turrets
- 55 Decayed Guardians
- 18 Sentries (found only around Divine Beast Vah Rudania)

Additionally, there are 3 Guardian Skywatchers and 1 Guardian Turret that are part of *The Champion's Ballad* DLC pack, and hence are not under the influence of Ganon.

Also, there are 367 Dead Guardians, of which 294 can be looted for ancient parts, and 47 can be flipped (for example, with Cryonis).

In particular, in the fields west of Fort Hateno (Blatchery Plain, Ash Swamp) there are 68 Dead Guardians and 2 Decayed Guardians.

Comment: Does this include mostly destroyed guardians, such as those at Akkala Tech Lab, or those submerged in lava at Death Mountain?

Comment: Does the number of Guardians plus Dead Guardians match the number of Guardians depicted on the tapestry?

Comment: @MatthewWells yes, they appear as dead guardians in the Object Map (look for `ruinguardian`, ignore the arms).